# Can you setup AWS cloudfront to have restricted & public files in the same distrubution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have an application where I want to serve static files to my customers.

To protect these files I'm using AWS cloud-front, and I've setup my distribution to require that you have a [signed url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) to access the files.

However there is 1 file on my CDN I want to make public to everyone, no restricted access required.

I know I could make a second Cloudfront distribution without security, and serve the file through that one. However this would make the client resolve 2 separate (sub)domains.

So ideally I would like all this to work from a single Cloudfront (sub)domain, but I don't know if it's possible.

I looked into signing a url that lasts forever, but it looks like there are too many things that can "invalidate" the url before it's expire time such as the tokens expiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look under the "Behaviors" tab of your cloudfront distribution. There you can specify different actions based on the path that is requested.

So if you want the public path to be at `/public` then you can add that as a new behavior and in that same window set `Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies)`to `No`.

There should already be a `Default(*)` behavior. When that new behavior is added it should be added as a higher precedence than the default behavior automatically.